# Is there any correlation between animal diet and blood pH?

Tags: physiology, diet, ph

The alkaline diet claim that as we humans have a slightly basic pH we shouldn't eat acidic food like meat (I think they claim that meat ashes are acid).

I was wondering that if carnivores animals share similar blood pH to humans and herbivores, that argument falls.

I did a google search, but I couldn't find the answer, even though it seems like basic data for a physiology textbook.
Similar questions have been posted here but without satisfactory answers.

Comment: The alkaline/acidic diet bit is all pseudoscience junk. You'll find related questions at Skeptics.SE. There are also a couple of diet pH questions here already if you search.

Comment: I know that it's pseudoscience. The question that I post is a scientific one that is meant to refute a pseudoscientific claim. I don't think the question to this specific question could be found in Skeptic.SE

Comment: Note that pH would not be the only factor to determine how much a type of food could influence the body pH. It would also be important to know the buffer capabilities of that food.